# Как сделать спойлер, по нажатию на один закрывается второй?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

Делаю спойлер, по нажатию появляется текст, как сделать чтобы по нажатию на один блок (спойлер), который закрыт, предыдущий который открыт закрылся автоматически?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.faq-item', function() {
  $(this).children('.faq-item__hide').slideToggle();
  $(this).children('.fa-up').toggleClass('animate-rotate');
  $(this).closest('.faq-item').toggleClass('faq-bg');
});
```

```html
<li class="faq-item">I have doubts.<i class="fas fa-chevron-up fa-up"></i>
  <p class="faq-item__hide">Contact our sales team.</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант на чистом js, я думаю вы без проблем перепишите на jquery

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("details");
sections.forEach((section) => section.addEventListener('toggle', toggleAcordeon));

function toggleAcordeon() {
  this.open && sections.forEach((section) => {
    if (section !== this && section.open) {
      section.open = false;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
details {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: .5em .5em 0;
}

summary {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: -.5em -.5em 0;
  padding: .5em;
}

details[open] {
  padding: .5em;
}

details[open] summary {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Section 1</summary>
  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </main>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Section 2</summary>
  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </main>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Section 3</summary>
  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </main>
</details>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.faq-item').on('click', acardion);
});

function acardion() {
  $(this).children('.faq-item__hide').not($(this).next()).slideToggle();
  $(this).prev().slideToggle();
  $(this).children('.fa-up').toggleClass('animate-rotate');
  $(this).closest('.faq-item').toggleClass('faq-bg');
}; Добрый день. Можно ли с этого вылепить что-то. Или только по условию отрытого блока ?

Comment: Думаю можно, пробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно вас путает универсальность toggle. Представьте что у вас есть два метода: открыть спойлер и закрыть спойлер. Когда вы кликаете на закрытый спойлер, вам надо просто закрыть все спойлеры, а потом открыть текущий. Не важно были ли какие-то спойлеры открыты ранее, просто закройте их все перед тем как открыть нужный.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.faq-item').on('click', acardion);
});

function acardion() {
  $(this).children('.faq-item__hide').not($(this).next()).slideToggle();
  $(this).prev().slideToggle();
  $(this).children('.fa-up').toggleClass('animate-rotate');
  $(this).closest('.faq-item').toggleClass('faq-bg');
};  Добрый день. Я попробовал вот такой вариант, но он не работает. Удаляет предыдущие блоки.

Comment: @Алексей ну создайте функции `openSpoiler($el)` и `closeSpoiler($el)`. Переработайте свой код, откажитесь от тогла. Чтобы понимать открыт спойлер или нет, добавьте элементу свойство `$el._isOpen = true` при открытии, и выставляйте `$el._isOpen = false` при закрытии.